# How to show in a view the total number of paragraphs for a node?

Tags: views, 8, nodes, paragraphs

I have a content type with a field of type paragraphs, with possible unlimited values. I need to show the total number of paragraphs for every node, in a column, in a views (table of fields). It seems to be only possible to render a preview of the paragraph. I tried to use "rewrite result" with "replacement patterns" but the only token available are the following:

```
{{ field_hours }} == Hours
{{ field_hours__target_id }} == Raw target_id
{{ field_hours__target_revision_id }} == Raw target_revision_id
```

How I can proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve this doing the following:

- Create a View to show Content of Type All. Add a page as well if you wish.
- Format the style to be a Table.
- Go to Advanced and turn on "Use aggregation".
- Go to aggregation settings for the field "Content:Title" and set the aggregation type to "Count".
- Change the label of this field to something like "Number of paragraphs in the node:".(*optional)
- In Fields add field "Content:Title", aggregation type should be Group results together.
- Add Filter Criteria "Hours (field_hours:target_id)", aggregation type should be Group results together, and set the operator to "is not empty(NOT NULL)".

This is how the Display settings should look at the end:
[image: Display settings]

And here are the desired results in the preview:

[image: Preview mode]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time Emily, this worked well